# Scraping table returns only “table” and not the contents of the table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urlopen

Imgae description is here:
[image]

Scraping table returns only “table” and not the contents of the table.
Here is my `code`:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://data.eastmoney.com/gdhs/detail/600798.html"

html = urlopen(url)


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

table = soup.find_all('table')

print(table)
```

Answer (score 0):

You found the table just fine with the code. Because the table is composed of multiple elements (tr/td), you have to loop through those to get the inner text of the table cells.

```
# This grabs the first occurrence of a table on the web page. If you want the second occurrence of a table on the web page, use soup.find_all('table')[1], etc.

table = soup.find_all('table')[0]

# Use a splice if there are table headers. If you want to include the table headers, use table('tr')[0:]

for row in table('tr')[1:]:
    print(row('td')[0].getText().strip())
```

Comment: Thx! But the code above still printed out nothing at the end. Nothing was shown in "table('tr')", but "[]".

Comment: I see now. I went to the web page and inspected the source code. It appears the hierarchy is as follows: <table><tbody><tr><td>. So what you would have to do is `table_body = table('tbody')`, then do `for row in table_body('tr')[0:]:` and keep the print statement. I can't confirm if that works right now, but should help a bit.